# Porting Linux compatible project from Windows to Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

In the company I'm working at we develop on Windows, Visual Studio, and cross compile for Linux using Eclipse. Our final application runs on Linux. I'm trying to convince them how easy and fast it is to build everything on Linux instead of using an old cross compiler and having all sort of weird bugs. Some of the bugs just vanish when I compile them with later versions of gcc on Linux. Also since the cross compiler is old we cannot use C++11 features.

One major problem I have is that since our projects are developed on Windows I'm having a really hard time with formatting the headers! For example assume I have a folder named `io` with a header file `Demo.h` in it. Then this

```
 #include <IO\demo.h>
```

works just fine on Windows. But on Linux it doesn't because Windows is not case sensitive and also both `\` and `/` work on Windows. On Linux it MUST be like this

```
#include <io/Demo.h>
```

otherwise I get an error that it can't find the specified header file. We have more than 20 main project that we are working on and each one is around 3-4 GB. I've already modified one of them. It took me around 7 hours to do it.

Are there any tools to help me make this transition faster?

Our source code is 95% C++ and the rest is C.

Comment: Yes, there is a tool for this. It's called `perl`. It shouldn't take more than half an hour, or so, to write a simple perl script that blows through the entire file hierarchy, and fixes up the `#include` pathnames.

Answer (score 4):

The official standard is to use `/` as the file path separator with the c-preprocessor to resolve paths in `#include` statements.

The usage of `\` seems to be a MSVC extension.

---

The *official* tools to solve such problems with large code bases under linux, are `sed` and `awk`.

---

Fixing the case sensitivity is bit of a tough thing, but could be done using some trickery with matching results from `find` ...